# FFmpeg e tempo de vídeo vs áudio

Tags: python, vídeo

Estou com uma aplicação simples que realiza o download de um video + áudio  e ' concatena ' ( Junta ) os mesmos com a ferramenta [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/), o problema é que na maioria das vezes o usuário vai baixar uma música maior que o vídeo em questão e então fica um vídeo de 10 segundos e o resto é uma tela travada com som de fundo ... alguém saberia me informar os parâmetros + explicação para que eu concatene a música exatamente na duração do vídeo ?

Código atual :

`ffmpeg -i {0}.{1} -i {2}.{3} -vcodec copy -acodec copy {4}.{5} && rm -rf {0}.{1} {2}.{3}`

Pesquisa : [Video and Audio file format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-and-Audio-file-format-conversion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que esteja usando via CLI, se o vídeo for mais curto que o audio você pode simplesmente usar:

```
-shortest (output)
```

> "Finish encoding when the shortest input stream ends."

---

Acredito que isso seja suficiente, para teste utilizei *via PowerShell*:

```
.\ffmpeg.exe `
-i "River - 6815.mp4" -i "Frontliner - Around The World (Extended Mix).wav" `
-c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -shortest "resultado.mp4"
```

O vídeo ([River - 6815.mp4](https://pixabay.com/pt/videos/rio-navio-%C3%A0-noite-rom%C3%A2ntico-6815/)) tem 13 segundos, enquanto que a musica ([Frontliner - Around The World (Extended Mix)](https://soundcloud.com/frontliner/frontliner-around-the-world-extended-mix-tsof2-12)) tem 4 minutos e 51 segundos de duração.

O vídeo final (resultado.mp4) ficou com 13 segundos no total e o vídeo e áudio foi unido normalmente.